# Shell command to remove the first string that is enclosed with slashes

Tags: shell, sed, awk

I need a shell command(sed or awk is preferred) to remove the string that is enclosed within the slashes.

For example If my string is `/some/dir/example/` then the output should be `dir/example/`

Comment: `dir` and example also enclosed within slashes. Please be specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `sed` you can do:

```
INPUT | sed 's|^/[^/]*/||'
```

But that's only necessary for file type data - for shell arguments you've already got the answer.

Answer (score 4):

```
 $ string=/some/dir/example/
 $ printf '%s\n' "${string#/*/}"
 dir/example/
```

That's POSIX shell syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Through `awk`,

```
$ echo '/some/dir/example/' | awk -F'/' -v OFS='/' '{ print $3,$4FS}'
dir/example/
```

OR

```
$ echo '/some/dir/example/' | awk -F'/' '{ print $3FS$4FS}'
dir/example/
```